# Custom function is not working in template

Tags: go, go-templates

I've the below that is working fine [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GXlDttQWcv8)

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    tmpl := `
{{ $slice := mkSlice "a" 5 "b" }}
{{ range $slice }}
     {{ . }}
{{ end }}
`
    funcMap := map[string]interface{}{"mkSlice": mkSlice}
    t := template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap(funcMap))
    template.Must(t.Parse(tmpl))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
}

func mkSlice(args ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    return args
}
```

But once I tried to run in from template file, nothing had been displayed, and no error had been recieved!

```golang
func mkSlice(args ...interface{}) []interface{} { // to ceate the array in the template
    return args
}

funcMap := map[string]interface{}{"mkSlice": mkSlice}
tmpl := template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap(funcMap))
template.Must(tmpl.ParseFiles("index.html"))
tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
```

And `index.html` is:

```html
{{ $slice := mkSlice "a" 5 "b" }}
{{ range $slice }}
    <span> {{ . }} </span>
{{ end }}
```

any thought?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see any errors because you don't check the error returned by `tmpl.Execute(w, nil)`. When do check it:

```
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

You'll see an output like:

```
panic: template: "" is an incomplete or empty template
```

The difference is that in the first case you used [`Template.Parse()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.Parse) method which:

> ... parses text as a template body for t.

Note that the template text you parse will be used for `t` itself!

In the second case you used [`Template.ParseFiles()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.ParseFiles) which:

> ... parses the named files and associates the resulting templates with t. If an error occurs, parsing stops and the returned template is nil; otherwise it is t. There must be at least one file. **Since the templates created by ParseFiles are named** by the base names of the argument files, t should usually have the name of one of the (base) names of the files.

So in your first example `t` contains a single template, and that single template will be executed by [`Template.Execute()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.Execute).

In your second example `t` contains multiple associated templates, `t` itself being an empty template, and another, associated template named `index.html`. You may execute that template using [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.ExecuteTemplate):

```
if err := t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "index.html", nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

For more information, see:

[Go template name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176355/go-template-name/41187671#41187671)

[The Go Template ParseFiles func parsing multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44979276/the-go-template-parsefiles-func-parsing-multiple-files/44979550#44979550)

Comment: Thanks, it is working. but displayed at `text` not as `html`, any idea?

Comment: You mean displayed as text and not as HTML? The output isn't HTML document.

Comment: I have the final statement as `tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", data)` which should be rendered as HTML, before trying to add the function it was rendering as HTML properly, ten I faced the issue, and now it is displayed in the browser as string

Comment: @HasanAYousef The template you showed in the question is not an HTML document, so I don't see why it should be rendered as HTML. If you have a different template, please show that. Also, if your output is HTML, use `html/template` instead of `text/template`.

Comment: Forget the text template I used it to display the issue, let's talk about `index.html`, though I'm using `html/template` but it is displayed as `text` knowing that before using the function it was rendered properly as html

Comment: @HasanAYousef Repeating myself: the example template you posted in the question is not an HTML document, there's no reason why it should be rendered as HTML. If you have a different template, please post it.

Comment: Hi, all this exercise was to reach this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903693/2441637, here in the template if I removed the `html` tag, the file is rendered as `string`, adding the `html` tag was not required before adding the custom function